# Controllers in vendor folders - my controllers - what is the right approach?

Tags: php, laravel, api, design-patterns

So I use a package from github ticketit(https://github.com/xaviqv/ticketit) and this package has controllers included.

And I integrated it into fresh laravel application.

now, I want to add an API endpoints into my application, my question is

should I copy the controllers from the ticketit package in the vendor directory and create my app/http/controllers folder or should I access the controllers in the vendor ? or are there any good design out there I should do?

so what i'm planning to do is

```
Route::get('api/v1/getdata','TicketsController@data');

Route::get('/getdata','TicketsController@data');
```

Please help on the design,

If I try to edit the controllers inside the vendor folders and upload it in server for sure it will not be upload.

btw, I'm using Laravel 5.4 and Laravel passport.

Comment: you can user directly ```Route::get('path', 'Kordy\Ticketit\Controllers\TicketsController@data')```

Comment: yes, but If I want to modify the Tickets controller, and If I upload it in the server for sure the vendor wouldn't be uploaded. how do i modify it and upload the changes as well?

Comment: Generally you shoud not modify vendor files. You can create new controller then include(extend) controller/s from vendor. Then you can override existing functions and in routes you should call this new method. Not 100% sure about this way, but I think this might work.

Comment: I see, so in this case I have to copy controllers from the vendor files to override the methods and create an if ($request-wantsJson()) return response() else render view.. thank you for your help @TIM

Comment: okay, it's not working, I've extended the my controller from the controller of the vendor package but it still redirect to the controller of the package, the package has also routes in it. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

[ticketit allows using of custom routes file](https://github.com/thekordy/ticketit/wiki/Custom-routes-and-customizing-Ticketit-functions), you can use that to point to your own custom controllers.

You can replace the default routes file by changing the `routes` path setting from administration panel `settings -> configuration -> initial -> routes`

as example:

If you want to change the behaviour of a single show, then you propably want to change the `TicketsController@show` method.

1. Make a new controller and make it extends `Kordy\Ticketit\Controllers\TicketsController`
2. copy `vendor/kordy/ticketit/src/routes.php` to anywhere such as `App\Http\ticketit_routes.php`
3. change the `$main_route_path` class to your new custom class: `Route::resource($main_route_path, 'App\Http\Controllers\SomeController', ..`
4. Go to the ticketit administration panel/menu `settings -> configuration -> Initial -> routes` and set routes to the full path of the `app/Http/ticketit_routes.php` file

[image: ticketit routes setting]